# Disable AutoDetectChanges on Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, record

someone knows how to disable the AutoDetectChanges on EFCore?

I need to do it because I have to make an huge import in my database, and can't find information on web.

Tried this but it's not working:

```
_context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Say configuration does not exist.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: ORMs are *NOT* meant for huge imports. Besides, you *do* want to track changes when importing - otherwise the ORM won't know what to insert

Comment: PS you already asked this. The answer remains the same. Don't use an ORM. You have no  Objects to Map to Relational tables, you only have rows. Using an ORM to insert 500K rows will result in roughly 500-500K times worse performance, depending on whether the ORM can batch INSERTs or not.

Comment: Even with EF Core 2.x's INSERT batching, you can't include more than 1K rows per batch, resulting in 500 separate INSERTs at best. *All* of those rows will be fully logged, resulting in a lot of IO and adding at least 2GB to the transaction log per 2GB file. SqlBulkCopy on the other hand will send all rows in a single stream using minimal logging

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you have tried

```
_context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

is for EF6.

The corresponding EF Core option [AutoDetectChangesEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.autodetectchangesenabled?view=efcore-3.1) is property of the [ChangeTracker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.changetracker?view=efcore-3.1) associated with the [DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext?view=efcore-3.1), so the corresponding code is

```
_context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 24):

I think the way I've done it before is when you register your DBContext you can turn it off so that you don't have to add it to every query.

Off the top of my head and don't have code ex. to reference right now so I could be wrong

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
});
```

EDIT: Found it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.usequerytrackingbehavior?view=efcore-3.1

Pretty sure this is what you're looking for

Comment: Switching off tracking is not the same as turning off automatic change detection. The latter is typically used to *postpone* change detection on tracked entities in order to win performance. I.e. at a later moment change detection will be executed explicitly in the code.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I'm familiar with, from the docs:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

**Ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: Thanks a lot! And if i use this one? _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

Comment: The OP wants to *insert* data. Disabling change tracking will prevent that

Comment: The two steps are connected. If you query data with no tracking then insert / update behavior with those entities will be affected. The downside of doing it is that EF will try to insert a record that already exists, or update a record that doesn't exist and get an error. I would assume OP's strategy accounts for that.

Comment: Switching off tracking is not the same as turning off automatic change detection. The latter is typically used to *postpone* change detection on tracked entities in order to win performance. I.e. at a later moment change detection will be executed explicitly in the code.